# Causes of a delayed Python sched execution

Tags: python, scheduled-tasks, virtualization

We are using the [sched](http://docs.python.org/library/sched.html) module in Python 2.6 to run a function every 60 seconds. Each call issues the sched.enter() function after executing with a delay of 60 and priority of 1. This has been working fine.

However, we have found a situation when the next execution of the sched function doesn't happen for several minutes, even up to 5-6 minutes later. This has been observed on a virtual machine.

What could be causing this? Is there any workaround to ensure the task gets executed regularly?

Comment: Are you sure that time is running continuously in your virtualized box ? I experienced some problems with virtual machines where time was running slowly than it should (something like 1 minute of time in virtual box was a few minutes in real time ).

Answer (score 0):

How long takes the processing that happens before `sched.enter` is called? I would suggest monitoring this, and maybe taking that processing time into account in the `delay` parameter of `sched.enter`.

The load of the VM and of the VM host may also be important factors. I've seen performance degradations in some apps caused by the VM host being under a too high load and swapping.

Comment: Processing usually takes a couple of seconds so it's not the task that gets triggered, the delay is definitely after sched.enter() gets called.

Comment: have you tried instrumenting sched.py with print statements to see where time is spent?

Comment: I don't think I can really do that since this is being seen on a production server and it might interfere with other usage of sched.

Comment: then try obtaining load figures for the VM and the underlying host.